# Select random 8 rows of data in SQL Server, need optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to select 8 random rows from different tables with conditions. I think I write good, but my code works very slowly. Maybe somehow I can write it easier or apply some kind of optimization to it?

It's working but taking 8 minutes and idk then stop it... Maybe code is not good too idk.

My code

```
SELECT TOP 8  
    a.vardas, m.miestoPavadinimas, ab.numeris, ab.sutartiesPradzia, 
    ab.sutartiesPabaiga, 
    Op.operatoriausPavadinimas,
    p.planoPavadinimas, Uzip.uzsakymoData as InternetPozymisNusakantis, 
    Uzp.uzsakymoData as PapildPozymisNusankantis
FROM 
    Asmuo AS a
INNER JOIN 
    Abonentas AS ab ON ab.asmensID = a.asmensID
INNER JOIN 
    Miestas AS m ON m.miestoID = a.miestoID
INNER JOIN 
    Planas AS p ON p.planoID = ab.planoID
INNER JOIN 
    Operatorius AS Op ON Op.operatoriausID = p.operatoriausID
INNER JOIN 
    InternetoPlanas AS itp ON itp.operatoriausID = Op.operatoriausID
LEFT JOIN 
    UzsakytasInternetoPlanas AS Uzip ON itp.internetoPlanoID = Uzip.internetoPlanoID 
LEFT JOIN 
    UzsakytaPapildomaPaslauga AS Uzp ON Uzp.abonentoID = Uzp.abonentoID 
WHERE 
    ((Uzip.uzsakymoData IS NOT NULL AND Uzip.atsisakymoData IS NULL) 
     OR
     (Uzp.uzsakymoData IS NOT NULL AND Uzp.atsisakymoData IS NULL))
ORDER BY 
    NEWID()
```

I can't find any solution.

Comment: Try it without `ORDER BY NEWID()`.

Comment: @avery_larry - then it won't be in random order (potentially)

Comment: Try read this: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: Well, run the query and get an "actual execution plan" and see what it shows you

Comment: @Milney That is true, but at least it won't be ordered.  I suppose it depends on whether or not "ANY" 8 rows -- even if they might be the same every time -- is sufficient to satisfy "random rows".  If not, maybe start with top  N (maybe 500) without an order and then do top 8 ordered by newid().  All of this, of course, presumes that order by newid() is the performance issue.

Comment: I need get random 8 rows, so i must use order by newid() or are some kind of alternatyve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach using `SELECT TOP x ... ORDER BY NEWID()` will basically assign a random number to every single record in the resulting query, after all the tables have been joined together, etc., and then sort the query by that number returning only the first `x` rows. For a query that returns many 100.000's of records, this approach is bound to be slow.

Assuming your main table `Asmuo` contains most of the records, and that the other tables are merely lookup tables, you can try to use the [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#tablesample-clause) clause on your main table, like so:

```
SELECT TOP 8
    ...
FROM
    Asmuo TABLESAMPLE (100 ROWS) AS a
INNER JOIN 
    ...
```

No `ORDER BY NEWID()` needed. The reason we pick 100 rows in TABLESAMPLE is because the number of records actually sampled can vary. More information [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1308/retrieving-random-data-from-sql-server-with-tablesample/).

If this still doesn't make the query perform fast enough, make sure the tables that are joined are properly indexed.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot, but i got some kind of problem now. My all rows is same. I try use DISTINCT, but its not help.